# Migrating Catch2 from v2 to v3 causes error

Tags: c++, cmake, c++14, catch2

I'm trying to migrate my C++ project to use Catch2 v3, but I ran into an error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `main'
```

Now, if I understand it correctly, the problem is, that I do not have a `main` function. I know, that in Catch2 v2, I could solve it by including

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
```

at one of my tests. I tried following the document on github, saying just replace

```
#include <catch2/catch.hpp>
```

with

```
#include <catch2/catch_all.hpp>
```

and remove the include, but obviously it did not work. Is the error in my test file or something is wrong with my Cmake setup (in that case I can provide the `CMakeLists.txt` files of my project)?

I have also changed systems since the previous build, probably the CMake and g++ has a higher version than at the previous builds.

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: The first step of their [migrating guide](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/migrate-v2-to-v3.md#how-to-migrate-projects-from-v2-to-v3) clearly decribes how to obtain definition of default `main` function. Have you tried to follow that guide?

Comment: The migration is a pain in the ass but they do have a guide on their site just like Tsyvarev pointed out. Also If I recall correctly - since V3 (or was it V2 already?) they abandoned the "header-only" policy and you actually have to compile it now. There were also some changes to the test macros. It's definitely not as straightforward as just changing a few lines.